# How to best calculate n-level aggregation data based on (n-1)-level data (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, analytic-functions

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939521/1915920) answer (with all executable simplified and documented sample code + helpful comments)

I did a kind of a trick there to calculate the last two rows of the following table:

```
DESCR                              SUM       
---------------------------------- ----------
money available in 2013            33233235.3
money spent in 2013                 4253235.3
money bound to contracts in 2013     34333500
money spent 2013 in % of available         12
money bound 2013 in % of available        103
```

Does anybody know of a better (performance, amount of code, understandability) way to do these kind of operations?

(Than to use the applied **"*provide unioned null row, fill with case and product()-over() on n+1 aggregation level*-trick"**, let's call it *punurofiwicapoonalt*-trick (naah ... still to complicated) ... sounds like - yeah - let's call it just ***porno*-trick** ;O) (... okay ... alias *capoon*-trick if you do not like it))

Comment: it is much more appropriate for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the `MODEL` syntax feature [hint from *GregV* in the Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/12278407#12278407) I could write this query really very short and precise without the need for *porno*. Cool!

So to easily check out the difference with my sample code and an at least *10g* Oracle db you just need to modify the original script linked above the following way:

```
        /**************************
         * the original sample query base data
         ***************************/
        ...  -- all content before the last select of the original example-SQL

        /**************************
         * the original sample porno-query
         ***************************/

        ,agg_porno as (
            select
                descr,

                ...  -- all the porno-query details

            from sum_data_lvl1
            /*
             DESCR                              SUM        AGG_LVL SUM_ID
             ---------------------------------- ---------- ------- ------
             money available in 2013            33233235.3       1 MA
             money spent in 2013                 4253235.3       1 MS
             money bound to contracts in 2013     34333500       1 MB
             money spent 2013 in % of available         12       2 MSP
             money bound 2013 in % of available        103       2 MBP
            */
        )

        /**************************
         * the new nice model-based query instead
         ***************************/

        ,agg_model as (
            select
                descr,
                trunc(s,1) as sum,
                agg_lvl,
                sum_id 
            from sum_data_lvl1
            model
                dimension by (sum_id)
                measures (descr, sum as s, agg_lvl)
                rules (
                    s['MSP'] = s['MS'] / s['MA'] * 100,
                    s['MBP'] = s['MB'] / s['MA'] * 100
                )
        )
        /*
         DESCR                              SUM        AGG_LVL SUM_ID
         ---------------------------------- ---------- ------- ------
         money available in 2013            33233235.3       1 MA
         money spent in 2013                 4253235.3       1 MS
         money bound to contracts in 2013     34333500       1 MB
         money spent 2013 in % of available       12.7       2 MSP
         money bound 2013 in % of available      103.3       2 MBP
         */

select * from agg_porno where 1=0  -- change to 1=1 to see these results
union all select * from agg_model where 1=1  -- change to 1=0 to hide these results
```