# Hierarchical Query Using Connect By

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ebs

Below is sample context looks similar to my real scenario.

Product: `XYZ  QTY:1`

Needs Raw Material `B,0.002` and Semi-Finished Item `A,0.001`. Produce A I required Raw Material `J,0.1` and semi-Finished Item `K,0.9`. Have product K I prior I need Raw Material G 0.004 `enter code here`and `T 0.005`.

I need to get a result of total needful all raw materials with it's cumulative quantities to produce `10` in quantity of product `XYZ`.

Comment: Does the solution need to use CONNECT BY? It's going to be more natural with a recursive WITH clause.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it has been downvoted because the title is very generic and the problem is hard to read. Also, I will not work further on a solution until you clarify whether you really need to use CONNECT BY (i.e. are you using Oracle less than 11gR2?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT component AS material, 10 * quantity AS quantity
  FROM (SELECT component, quantity,
               CASE WHEN CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 THEN 'Raw' ELSE 'Semi-Finished' END AS type
     FROM bill_of_materials
    START WITH item = 'XYZ' CONNECT BY PRIOR component = item)
 WHERE type = 'Raw'
```

Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/697fa/6/0) gives:

```
J |        1
G |     0.04
T |     0.05
B |     0.02
```

Comment: I forgot about multiplying the factors down the tree. Will rethink this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by @KenGeis, for Oracle 11g you can use recursive query:

```
with t (p, i , q) as (
  select product, ingredient, qty from test where product = 'XYZ'
  union all 
  select product, ingredient, qty*q from test, t where product = i)
select i, sum(q) qty from t 
  where not exists (select 1 from test where product = i) group by i;
```

If for some reasons you need `connect by` version, here is my try:

```
with t1 as (
  select ingredient i, sys_connect_by_path(ingredient, '/') path1, 
         sys_connect_by_path(qty, '/') path2
    from test where connect_by_isleaf = 1 connect by prior ingredient = product
    start with product = 'XYZ' ),
t2 as (
  select i, path1, path2, trim(regexp_substr(path2, '[^/]+', 1, lines.column_value)) val
    from t1,
      table (cast (multiset(
        select level from dual connect by level < regexp_count(t1.path2, '/')+1
        ) as sys.ODCINumberList ) ) lines)
select i, sum(s) qty
  from (select i, exp(sum(ln(val))) s from t2 group by i, path1) group by i
```

<sup>[SQL Fiddle demo for both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c9c08/1)</sup>

Subquery `t1` generates list of needed raw ingredients and in column path2 - factors which we need to multiply. 
`t2` *unpivots* these values, final query performs multiplication and groups results in case if there 
were two semi-finished items which uses same raw material.
For multiplication I used answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403924/is-there-a-product-function-like-there-is-a-sum-function-in-oracle-sql) SO question.