# Product in a GROUP BY with potential zeroes

Tags: sql, oracle

So I [searched a bit and found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403924/is-there-a-product-function-like-there-is-a-sum-function-in-oracle-sql) that you can do a product of rows in Oracle using a GROUP BY and a nifty mathematical formula: `exp(sum(ln(some_col)))`. It's pretty awesome, but unfortunately doesn't work when `some_col` is potentially zero (because `ln(0)` is not possible as ln(x) is negative infinity as it approaches zero).

Example query:

```
select
  a, b, c
  sum(d) d,
  sum(e) e,
  exp(sum(ln(f))) f
from x
group by a, b, c;
```

Obviously since this is a product of values, if one of them is zero, the product would be zero. The immediate thought would be to use a `case`, but that would require the case statement to be on an aggregate value or something in the GROUP BY... which it isn't. I can't just exclude those rows because I still need `sum(d)` and `sum(e)`.

Any thoughts on a good way to do this while dealing with potential zeroes? I was thinking about something involving `over(partition by ...)`, but in reality, my query groups by 12 columns and there are 20 other columns being aggregated. That query could get reeaaaal ugly, but if it's the only solution, I suppose I don't have a choice.

Side question: is there any particular reason there isn't a product function in Oracle? Seems like it'd be such a basic thing to include like `sum` is.

**Note:** This is Oracle 12c.

Example:

If I had an input table like this (matching with the query above):

```
| a   | b   | c   | d | e | f |
+-----+-----+-----+---+---+---+
| foo | bar | hoo | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| foo | bar | hoo | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| foo | bar | hoo | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| foo | bar | mee | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| foo | bar | mee | 3 | 4 | 3 |
```

I would expect output like this:

```
|  a  |  b  |  c  | d | e  | f |
+-----+-----+-----+---+----+---+
| foo | bar | hoo | 6 | 11 | 0 |
| foo | bar | mee | 4 | 6  | 6 |
```

However, because the third row has a 0 for `f`, we naturally get `ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range` for `ln(0)`.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added a clear example.

Comment: Does exp(sum(case when f != 0 then ln(f) end)) work ?

Comment: @GaryMyers Unfortunately, that results in a `NULL` which is not exactly what we want here. That said, I could toss an `nvl` around it after that, so it would possibly work. So, in total: `nvl(exp(sum(case when f != 0 then ln(f) end)), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `log(0)` is not undefined - it's negative infinity.

Second: in Oracle you *can* generate a negative infinity, but you'll have to use BINARY_FLOAT.

```
select a, b, c,
       sum(d) d,
       sum(e) e,
       exp(sum(CASE WHEN f <> 0 THEN ln(f) ELSE -1/0F END)) f
  from x
  group by a, b, c;
```

Using your data this generates:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
foo bar hoo 6   11  0
foo bar mee 4   6   6.0000001304324524E+000
```

Note that introducing logarithms and power functions will introduce some rounding issues, but this should at least get you started.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ec8982045329e83de19c4a94467cccc)

TO NEGATIVE INFINITY...AND BEYOND!!!!!!

:-)

Comment: Interesting. Embrace the negative infinity. I was thinking I could add a tiny epsilon and round the result (e.g. `round(exp(sum(ln(f + 0.000001))), 4)`) too, but we can use negative infinity to our benefit too.

Comment: `BINARY_FLOAT` (or `BINARY_DOUBLE`) isn't just required to get infinity semantics, it's also *drastically* faster than `NUMBER` when used with `EXP()` or `LN()`, [as I've shown here](https://blog.jooq.org/oracles-binary_double-can-be-much-faster-than-number/)