# Column containing the product of elements in a second column, sorted by group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL script,

```
Select To_Char(A1.Date1, 'dd-mm-yyyy') As  Date, B1.bm, A1.Number
From A1 
Inner Join Benchmarkdefs B1 On (A1.Bmik = B1.Bmik);
```

,
which yields,

```
Date        BM  Number
11-08-2021  AA  1
12-08-2021  AA  2
13-08-2021  AA  3
14-08-2021  AA  4
15-08-2021  AA  5
11-08-2021  BB  12
12-08-2021  BB  13
13-08-2021  BB  14
14-08-2021  BB  15
15-08-2021  BB  16
11-08-2021  CC  22
12-08-2021  CC  23
13-08-2021  CC  24
14-08-2021  CC  25
15-08-2021  CC  26
```

I wish to create a column, `Product`, that contains the product of `Numbers` on each date within the same `BM` group:

```
Date        BM  Number  Product sum             
11-08-2021  AA  1       120             
12-08-2021  AA  2       120             
13-08-2021  AA  3       120             
14-08-2021  AA  4       120             
15-08-2021  AA  5       120             
11-08-2021  BB  12      524160              
12-08-2021  BB  13      524160              
13-08-2021  BB  14      524160              
14-08-2021  BB  15      524160              
15-08-2021  BB  16      524160              
11-08-2021  CC  22      524160              
12-08-2021  CC  23      7893600             
13-08-2021  CC  24      7893600             
14-08-2021  CC  25      7893600             
15-08-2021  CC  26      7893600
```

To clarify, for BM ='AA' the product should be `1*2*3*4*5=120`.

Thank you in advance!
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in product function; but you could use [the exp/ln technique from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403924/266304), and adapt it to use an analytic sum:

```
select to_char(a1.date1, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date1, b1.bm, a1.number1,
  round(cast(exp(sum(ln(cast(a1.number1 as binary_double))) over (partition by b1.bmik)) as number)) as product
from a1 
inner join benchmarkdefs b1 on (a1.bmik = b1.bmik);
```

| DATE1 | BM | NUMBER1 | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-08-2021 | AA | 2 | 120 |
| 11-08-2021 | AA | 1 | 120 |
| 13-08-2021 | AA | 3 | 120 |
| 14-08-2021 | AA | 4 | 120 |
| 15-08-2021 | AA | 5 | 120 |
| 12-08-2021 | BB | 13 | 524160 |
| 11-08-2021 | BB | 12 | 524160 |
| 13-08-2021 | BB | 14 | 524160 |
| 15-08-2021 | BB | 16 | 524160 |
| 14-08-2021 | BB | 15 | 524160 |
| 11-08-2021 | CC | 22 | 7893600 |
| 12-08-2021 | CC | 23 | 7893600 |
| 14-08-2021 | CC | 25 | 7893600 |
| 13-08-2021 | CC | 24 | 7893600 |
| 15-08-2021 | CC | 26 | 7893600 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=960de2e9a9d9ca417d51fad091618ad8) showing some of the intermediate steps.

The column names in your example are illegal so I assume you just changed those for posting; so I've modified them slightly to make them valid.

Note that if your number can be zero then you may need to exclude that to prevent it erroring; if you have negative values you'll need to handle those differently too; and you might want to adjust the `round()` precision depending on your real data too.

Comment: Thank you, @Alex. I am aware that I did not specify this in my question, but if I were to subtract the number 1 from the product, where or how should I include the '-1' in `round(cast(exp(sum(ln(cast(a1.number1 as binary_double))) over (partition by b1.bmik)) as number)) as product`

Comment: @CecilieS.K - anywhere outside the `exp()`; but for simplicity might as well be at the end before `as` - so `round(...) -1 as product`